# SideBarNavViewComponent NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

My company uses ASP.NET Boilerplate, the web framework.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at LiboPark.Web.Views.Shared.Components.SideBarNav.SideBarNavViewComponent.InvokeAsync(String activeMenu) in E:\ParkSystem\aspnet-core\src\LiboPark.Web.Mvc\Views\Shared\Components\SideBarNav\SideBarNavViewComponent.cs:line 43
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentInvoker.InvokeAsyncCore(ObjectMethodExecutor executor, ViewComponentContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentInvoker.InvokeAsync(ViewComponentContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentHelper.InvokeCoreAsync(ViewComponentDescriptor descriptor, Object arguments)
```

I find it hard to solve.

I want to solve this problem, or change the system architecture.

Comment: `SideBarNavViewComponent` is not from the template ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/tree/master/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Views/Shared/Components)), so you'd have to provide more details. Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please share the related codes and then we could help you.